# What body style is this guitar?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

Based on descriptions I've read it seems like an auditorium or grand auditorium, but I am not certain.

These pictures are of another guitar of the same model as mine:

[image]
[image]
<sub>(source: [guitar-museum.com](http://www.guitar-museum.com/uploads/guitar/122/200253170749-1.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [guitar-museum.com](http://www.guitar-museum.com/uploads/guitar/122/200253170749-5.jpg))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [guitar-museum.com](http://www.guitar-museum.com/uploads/guitar/122/200253170749-4.jpg))</sub>

Articles about body style and string gauge:

- [http://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/guitar-buying-guides/how-to-choose-the-right-acoustic-guitar-strings](https://web.archive.org/web/20190312032952/https://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/guitar-buying-guides/how-to-choose-the-right-acoustic-guitar-strings)
- [http://www.guitarfriendly.net/best-acoustic-guitar-strings/](https://web.archive.org/web/20190908070212/http://guitarfriendly.net:80/best-acoustic-guitar-strings/)

Comment: I've never heard of a link between body style and string gauge. Can you explain that?

Comment: The second link was written by someone who doesn't understand what a truss rod is, so that source should not be trusted, IMHO. Comfort, tone, and intonation are such big factors when selecting string gauge that if there's any effect that body style has, it is likely overshadowed. Generally you want to play the heaviest strings that are comfortable but you have to have your truss rod adjusted to match the strings. I can't imagine 10s on an acoustic, they would sound so wimpy, and 11s can't be much better. I would start at 12s unless your guitar is really terrible.

Comment: Thanks for the information Todd! Out of curiosity, do you have any idea what body style my guitar is?

Comment: [This article](https://www.premierguitar.com/articles/_Acoustic_Size_Matters) draws a much more reasonable link between body style, **scale length**, comfort. Larger bodies likely have longer scale lengths and therefore may be harder to play with heavier strings, so you actually might want *lighter* strings for a larger guitar. I agree the guitar pictured looks like an auditorium or maybe grand auditorium. But those are just names so they don't have a 100% link with the real world.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "correct" strings for a body style. I'd consider .012s light on an acoustic, and work up from there. Different gauges will sound different on the same guitar; you'll have to try some to see what you like best. As for the actual body style of your guitar, I don't know that there is a rigorous classification system. [Here is a link](http://danlovesguitars.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-acoustic-guitar-sizes-part-i-small-guitars/) that talks about this a bit.

Comment: Thanks for all of the info guys. I really appreciate it. @DavidBowling when you mention .012s you're talking about the gauge of the high string right?

Comment: Yes. That is just a loose way of referring to string gauges, but different sets can be made up of different gauges. Some players like lighter strings on top, and heavier strings on bottom-- I think that bluegrass players often favor this arrangement.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve replaced casual guitar playing friends’ strings with .011s and they are very happy with them. By casual I mean they don’t play every day, pretty much just strum open chords, and rarely play with others where volume is a factor. Going from .012s to .011s did not require a new setup (like a lot of sub-premium “beginner” guitars, the actions were a bit high to begin with,) but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a `cutaway` because the bottom underneath the neck is "cut away' to allow you to reach some of the higher frets more comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

The terms "auditorium" or "grand auditorium", as well as "concert", "grand concert" etc. are generally referring to the **size** of guitars, rather than their shapes. I think the misunderstanding begins from Taylor started using these terms to describe their guitar shapes; but size-wise, Taylor's understanding is a bit different than other brands (i.e. Martin and its derivatives). For example, Martin considers its Size 0000, or "M" series guitar as grand auditorium size, but Taylor's Grand Auditorium designs (*14) are a bit bigger than that.

Since Taylor's naming convention is also becoming a standard nowadays, it's actually a shoe-size problem. So the question here is, which standard will you adopt? Then you can measure the guitar yourself and look up [Martin's Size Chart](https://www.martinguitar.com/features-materials/sizetype/) or [Taylor's](https://www.taylorguitars.com/guitars/acoustic/shapes/overview) to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

That body style is a Grand Auditorium as per Taylor guitars. Its a versatile shape with the cut away and wide lower bout.

There is a great article here on [Acoustic guitar body shapes](https://killerrig.com/different-types-of-acoustic-guitar-body-shapes-and-sizes/) that will help you understand the names and how they are categorized by different brands.

String gauge is irrelevant as the guitar can be set up for most within reason. Just depends on your sound preference and type of music.

Answer (score 0):

My read is that it's an Ibanez AEG, and with the pretty wood on top, likely an AEG70. This is reading as Grand Concert, and it has a 3/4-width body. The thinner body is easier to reach around but would be somewhat quieter, which is okay, because it has a piezo pickup.

You want the big-bodied dreadnaught and the heavy strings for volume, but since you have modern technology, you don't *need* all that to be heard. Medium strings — .013-.056 — should be enough to make it move without us being too much too for your fingers. Maybe even .012s.